# ¿Como hacer para reconocer cuando un objeto esta modificado en una condición while?

Tags: java

He encontrado una cosa que me ha sorprendido con los objetos de clases en Java.

Opongo a una lista de cláusulas `ListeClauses` un `goal` que esta modificado cada vez que se puede unificar con `unif` (un método creado por mi propio) una cláusula con el `goal`. Por eso, quiero empezar de nuevo a menos de que el `goal` ya no fue modificado.

Aunque el `goal` no esta modificado por el codigo expresamente, cada vez que cambio `goal`, cambio `newGoal`.

Pienso que esta a causa de `newGoal=goal;`

```
    int ir = Clause.ListeClauses.size()-1;
    Clause goal=new Clause();
    goal =(Clause) Clause.ListeClauses.get(ir);
    Clause newGoal =new Clause();
    boolean result = false;

    while (goal!=newGoal){
        newGoal=goal;
        for(int i=0;i<ir;i++){

            Clause c1 =new Clause();
            c1 =(Clause)Clause.ListeClauses.get(i);



            System.out.println("c" +i + ": "+ c1);
            System.out.println("goal: " + goal);

            if (goal.unif(c1)){

                goal.remove(0);
                c1.remove(0);
                goal.addAll(c1);
                System.out.println("UNIFICATION DONE\ngoal: " + goal+"\n**********");

            }
        }
    }
```

Entonces, este ciclo esta hecho solamente una vez de toda manera, que no esta lo que busco.

**¿Como hacer, entonces para reconocer cuando fue modificado el objeto?**

Comment: Según entiendo, quieres aplicar el método `unif` para todos los `Clause` que se encuentran en `Clause.ListeClauses` de manera que solo exista un solo `Clause`. ¿Cierto?

Comment: Si, quiero plicar el método unif para todos los Clause que se encuentran en Clause.ListeClauses con goal. ¿Pero que significas cuando dices "de manera que solo exista un solo Clause"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes tener cuidado con comparación de objetos por medio de operadores lógicos. Si estás comparando que los dos objetos apuntan o no a la misma dirección de memoria, es correcto usar `=`. De lo contrario, si deseas comparar la igualdad de ambos objetos, lo correcto es usar `equal`.

Si deseas verificar si un objeto ha sido modificado previamente, puedes guardar una copia del objeto antes de la iteración y en cada iteración comparar el objeto actual con el temporal por medio de `equal`.

Ahora, hablas de **unificar**. Es decir, si quieres unificar objetos la mejor opción es clonarlos:

`newGoal = (Clause) goal.clone();`

Este punto es debatible, ya que como recomienda Joshua Bloch en su libro `Effective Java`, es mucho mejor hacer un *deep clone* (clonación profunda), es decir, a nivel de bytes.

Comment: ¡Cuidado! El método `clone` debería ser sobre escrito y [**es mejor no utilizarlo**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5802118/1065197).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ¿Ha? ¿Y como puedo hacer un copy constructor desde hace?

Comment: @Marine1 editas tu clase para agregarle un nuevo constructor donde acepte un objeto de la misma clase. Dentro de ese constructor, aplicas la lógica necesaria para *clonar* el objeto. Algo así: `public MiClase(MiClase otro) { this.campo1 = otro.campo1; this.campo2 = otro.campo2; /* lo mismo con todos los campos necesarios */ }`

Comment: @Marine1 Mira esteejemplo: http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-deep-clone-example-source-code sobre cómo hacer una clonación efectiva como recomienda Joshua Bloch.

Comment: @MitsuGarcía tener cuidado con eso. Justo aquí en el sitio hay una pregunta donde al realizar esa estrategia en el clonado le surgió `OutOfMemoryError`.

Answer (score 2):

Dado que tienes una colección de elementos y lo que necesitas es aplicar cierto método para unir todos los elementos de esa colección, y si utilizas Java 8, puedes ahorrarte todo ese código al utilizar streams y el método [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
Clause union = new Clause();
Clause.ListeClauses.stream().reduce(union, (clause1, clause2) -> {
    if (clause1.unif(clause2)) {
        clause1.addAll(clause2);
    }
});
System.out.println(union);
```

En caso que no utilices Java 8, el concepto es el mismo: debes unir todos los resultado de tu colección aplicando algún método ya definido. Para lograr ello, puedes aplicar la lógica que utiliza `Stream#reduce` detrás de las escenas (pseudo código):

```
Clause result = null;
for (Clause element : Clause.ListeClauses) {
    if (result == null) {
        //el primero de la lista
        result = element;
    } else {
        //del segundo en adelante
        if (result.unif(element) {
            result.addAll(element);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```